# Replace Text inside a bracket with a form field in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to replace the text inside a `[ ]` bracket with web form fields in C#, What is the best way to perform it.

```
"Complaint No [Complaint No] from [PARTY NAME]logged. Please assign Engineer at [SITE ADDRESS]"
```

Expected Output :- Complaint no **1234** from **ABC** logged. Please Assign engineer at **SiteLocation**

Comment: have you tried anything? you would need to provide more information, your question is not clear enough at this point. You propose 3 different replacements, apparently dependent on the text inside the brackets. Is the text inside the bracket always the same? what is the degree of variability here? there are a lot of different approaches to this problem.

Comment: @MongZhu  i am trying,  text inside the bracket is remains always same.

Comment: please edit your post and add this information to it. It belongs into the post not the comment

Comment: MSDN [How to modify string contents in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/modify-string-contents), and perhaps you don't even need to Modify the string you can build it the right way from the start like `var result = $"Hello, {name}! Today is {date.DayOfWeek}, it's {date:HH:mm} now.";`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use String.Format().

```
String.Format("Complaint No {0} from {1} logged. Please assign Engineer at {2}", Complaint_No, Party_Name, Site_Address);
```

store the data you want to print in Complaint_No, Party_Name, Site_Address these string or if you are retriving it the pass it to the string and use the above fromat.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't give information from where the data come from, I cannot be more especific.
I have storaged your data in three differents strings.

```
string complaint_no = "1234";
string party_name = "ABC";
string site_address = "SiteLocation";
string result = String.Format("Complaint No {0} from {1} logged. Please assign Engineer at {2} \n", complaint_no, party_name, site_address);
```

Explanation:  The  `{number}` are going to transform into the string with the same number position. You can use variables or raw strings in this positions.

You can try it here online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eHui4D